# Load Balancer in AWS: Health checks failed [502] after adding SSL certificate

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ssl-certificate, load-balancing

I have an Amazon EC2 instance that is web portal. I want to install a SSL certificate (HTTPS) with EC2 Load Balancer

So I create a Certificate Manager and validate it with DNS Validation, and add the CNAME in the Route 53.

Until here I think I still have everything correct.

Then I create a Load Balancer and attach the SSL certificate to my EC2 instance but in the registered targets drops me:

- Status: Unhealthy
- Description: Health checks failed with these codes: [502]

[image: Targets]

Does anybody knows what do I have to check or change to make it work?

For now I am checking the status of the registered targets.

Comment: Your instance is returning a 502 error in response to the health checks.  Review the web server/application logs on the instance.

Comment: Which port you listen in your instance?

Comment: 443 and 80 both are open.

Comment: `listen` not `open`

Comment: The listeners http:80 and https:443 attach with the ssl certificate